# how to get NSmutable array from the NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone

I have use below syntax for for set the object.

```
[dict setObject:eventArray forKey:categoryName];
```

Now i am trying to get below syntax but i got nothing.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArrayValue=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempArrayValue =[tempDict valueForKey:categoryValue];
```

What is the problem i cant understand can u help me?

Comment: You are using 'dict' to set the eventArray,  and 'tempDict' to retrieve it.  If that is not the problem, show us the entire code

Comment: is [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] really necessary here?

Answer (score 0):

you have given key as categoryName not categoryValue, and while retrieving you are using categoryValue.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArrayValue=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; tempArrayValue =[tempDict valueForKey:categoryName];
```

Comment: in CategoryName and Categoryvalue contain same data

Comment: are dict and tempDict have the same value?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the value like this:

```
[dict setObject:eventArray forKey:categoryName];
```

Then you should be fetching it back again like this:

```
NSMutableArray* eventArray = [dict valueForKey:categoryName];
```

assuming that eventArray is of type `NSMutableArray`.

What you are doing has at least two different problems.

This line is a memory leak, since you allocate an object and then throw it away, so delete it:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArrayValue=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

This second line may return a nil object, if there is no object stored for the key categoryValue. (You are using an object called categoryName above, as the key to store the value):

```
tempArrayValue =[tempDict valueForKey:categoryValue];
```

You haven't posted enough code to be able to tell why it's not working otherwise.